# Can DVI look different?

Tags: dvi

I have a desktop with an nVidia GT 9500 which has two DVI slots. I have a 24" TN-Panel TFT on that and it looks pretty good. Then I hooked it onto the DisplayPort of my ThinkPad with the Intel HD 3000 card with an DP->DVI adapter and I think that the fonts look even clearer.

Both computers run Kubuntu 12.04, although the ThinkPad is freshly set up, while the desktop is migrated from the previous release.

Is this a hardware thing or is it just some setting in the anti-aliasing or sub-pixel-hinting?

Comment: Well, what *are* your anti-aliasing/sub-pixel hinting settings in both machines?

Comment: I did not change anything, and I am not sure where to look :-/

Comment: so... to be clear (no pun intended), you were looking at the same display image (of what... your Kubuntu desktop?) at the same exact resolution, and you believe the Display Port to DVI adapted connection from the ThinkPad looked better than the straight DVI connection from the desktop?  The key in this comment is **same resolution**.

Comment: It is 1920x1200 on both computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a display port to DVI adapter change the quality of text on the screen? No.

Can the display look different between two different video card vendors? Yes. Different video card vendors use different drivers which have slight variations in the visual processing. The driver stack for each architecture is completely different so it's expected to find variation.

If I had to guess, they optimized the driver in the Intel chip to make your fonts look different.

You can always update your nVidia drivers to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Okay, so if the font is rendered within the graphics card, that would make sense.